# MySQL: Count not existing values

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server

I try to program a solution where I have multiple linked tables.

`table1` contains rows with ids in field `k_id`

`table2` contains rows where each row has a `k_id` assigned (as `s_k_id`) but any k_id may have multiple rows in `table2`. Any entry in `table2` can only have one `k_id`

Now I want to have the count (and late probably a list) of `k_ids` which are not used in `table2` as `s_k_id`.

I hope you can understand my question.

My solution would be this, but I assume it can be solved better?

```
SELECT count(k_id) AS `count` FROM tabel1 WHERE k_id NOT IN (SELECT s_k_id FROM table2)
```

How can I achieve this better? (Please include a short description what your SQL-Statement is doing)

Thank you!

Comment: What is wrong with the query that you already have?

Answer (score 1):

You can try

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT k_id) count 
  FROM table1 t1 LEFT JOIN table2 t2
    ON t1.k_id = t2.s_k_id
 WHERE t2.s_k_id IS NULL
```

or

```
SELECT COUNT(k_id) count 
  FROM table1 t
 WHERE NOT EXISTS
(
    SELECT *
      FROM table2
     WHERE s_k_id = t.k_id
)
```

Here is  **[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/451f8e/4)** demo

Comment: Did it help? Do you need more help with your question?